# binding usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

How can I create a binding to a property defined in an UserControl from XAML which includes it? For example, I have a control of type local:Photo named thePhoto, which has three controls local:Layer called Main, Frame and Text, and I want to access thePhoto.Main.ActualWidth from my MainWindow? Thanks

(I forgot to say that simple Binding with Path and ElementName doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DependencyProperty` of desired type within "parent" `UserControl` and bind it with needed Properties on both sides.
Nice example of doing stuff like that:
[Exploring the use of Dependency Properties in User Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224230/Exploring-the-use-of-Dependency-Properties-in-User)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Now I see... How complicated! The author himself slams the mechanism...
BTW, as far as I see, he only binds to predefined properties (like SelectedItem), which is not the case in my question.